# Getting a sub string of undetermined length, starting at the end of the string

Tags: sql-server

I have a series of part numbers which are usually only 10 characters, but sometimes contain an extra 2 or 3 at the beginning.  I want a distinct list of all of these parts excluding the last 5 characters which only contain size information.  Obviously a simple sub-string doesn't work and as far as I know there isn't similar to rtrim() which allows specification of character ranges.  I posted my solution below, but I think it's somewhat sloppy and wanted to know if there is a better way?

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(P.ID),6,LEN(P.ID))),
    P.DESCRIPTION
FROM REQUIREMENT R 
INNER JOIN OPERATION O ON
    R.WORKORDER_BASE_ID = O.WORKORDER_BASE_ID AND 
    R.WORKORDER_LOT_ID = O.WORKORDER_LOT_ID AND
    R.WORKORDER_SUB_ID = O.WORKORDER_SUB_ID
INNER JOIN PART P ON
    P.ID = R.PART_ID
    WHERE O.RESOURCE_ID LIKE '%17%'
    AND P.ID LIKE '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
    AND P.DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE '%OBS%'
    AND O.STATUS_EFF_DATE > GETDATE() - 365*2
```

Comment: What's wrong with `Left(value, len(value) - 5)`?

Comment: Absolutely nothing. I can't believe I didn't think of that.  Thanks!

Comment: You really should be using DATEADD(year, -2, GETDATE()) instead of your shorthand math. It is more clear, accurate and less prone to datatype errors. https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of that function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you've worded this, is you want to strip off the last five characters.  There are two ways to do this.  One, just pull off all but the last five characters, and the other is to use REVERSE, pull off the first 5, and REVERSE again.  You did the latter in your example, but this is the other alternative:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@string, 1, LEN(@string) - 5)
```

Is that not what you want?

Comment: It is.  Thanks.  Once again, I'm not sure why I didn't think to do that.